# Slowness opening and moving around within large files

Tags: spacemacs, motion

I'm running spacemacs `0.200.13` on emacs `25.3.1` from a macOS `10.12` machine.

In some scenarios, things feel very sluggish. They get worse as a dozen buffers or so are opened during the day. From the information below, how could I improve things?

I've started disabling `linum-relative-mode` and this has been helpful. Although having to disable line numbering is quite impractical from a text editor...

Opening and navigating in a file that contains about a thousand lines, here is the result of a profiler run:

```
- command-execute                                         136,548,463  75%
 - call-interactively                                     136,548,463  75%
  - funcall-interactively                                 106,982,148  59%
   - spacemacs/helm-find-files                             62,811,296  34%
    - let*                                                 62,811,296  34%
     + helm-find-files-1                                   62,806,176  34%
     + cond                                                     5,120   0%
   + helm-M-x                                              21,400,635  11%
   + evil-goto-line                                        12,380,900   6%
   + org-cycle                                              8,550,289   4%
   + evil-next-line                                         1,012,448   0%
   + evil-previous-line                                       826,580   0%
  + byte-code                                              29,566,315  16%
+ linum-update-current                                     35,843,195  19%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                           6,892,632   3%
+ timer-event-handler                                         817,048   0%
+ winner-save-old-configurations                               32,416   0%
```

Editing a JSX file that's only 200 lines, here is the profiler:

```
- command-execute                                          67,036,616  71%
 - call-interactively                                      67,034,504  71%
  - funcall-interactively                                  35,498,016  38%
   - helm-M-x                                              25,212,868  26%
    - command-execute                                      25,212,868  26%
     - call-interactively                                  25,212,868  26%
      - byte-code                                          15,288,051  16%
       - completing-read                                   15,288,051  16%
        + #<compiled 0x46658893>                           15,288,051  16%
      + funcall-interactively                               9,924,785  10%
   + spacemacs/kill-this-buffer                             4,504,190   4%
   + evil-previous-line                                     2,680,056   2%
   + evil-ex                                                  729,371   0%
   + evil-next-line                                           695,756   0%
   + evil-delete                                              511,784   0%
   + evil-paste-after                                         384,176   0%
   + evil-search-next                                         235,082   0%
   + evil-window-down                                         154,040   0%
   + profiler-report-toggle-entry                              76,249   0%
   + evil-visual-line                                          67,808   0%
   + evil-end-of-line                                          52,896   0%
   + evil-goto-first-line                                       7,520   0%
  + byte-code                                              30,176,090  32%
  + list                                                    1,359,342   1%
+ linum-update-current                                     14,198,340  15%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                           6,652,776   7%
+ timer-event-handler                                       3,692,719   3%
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure how this works out on spacemacs, but replacing `linum-mode` with `nlinum-mode` (from GNU ELPA) or `display-line-numbers-mode` (requires Emacs 26) could help.

Comment: Also, in my opinion if you are looking for performance, replacing spacemacs with your own configuration may be your best bet.